# android studio theme doesnt change

Tags: java, android

I have a problem at the change the app theme

I have two activity splashscreen and main activity

splashscreen theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"
```

main activity theme

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

My question : Everything is very good . but theme doesnt change main activtiy theme

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"
```

doesnt change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the theme you have set on the application level

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any codes to change style in your MainActivity.java?
I rather than write code in activity's onCreate method when I want to hide title:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```